# Set tooltip hint for `Select` widget in Vaadin Flow 14

Tags: popup, tooltip, vaadin, vaadin-flow

In Vaadin 14.1, the [`TextField`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/textfield/TextField.html) widget offers a `setTitle` method. We can pass a string to that method, with the text appearing at runtime as a floating [tooltip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tooltip) message when the user hovers their mouse pointer.

Surprisingly, the [`Select`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/14.1.5/com/vaadin/flow/component/select/Select.html) widget lacks a `setTitle` method.

➥ Is there some way to get this same tooltip behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have access to the DOM basically and can directly add a `title` attribute.  E.g.

```
select.getElement().setAttribute('title', 'This is a title')
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the game, but the Vaadin Tooltip component is also a good option. It's now Apache licensed. See [*Component Factory Tooltip for Vaadin 10+*](https://github.com/vaadin-component-factory/tooltip#component-factory-tooltip-for-vaadin-10).

[image: screenshot of Tooltip component in action]