# How to add hover texts to Vaadin components?

Tags: vaadin

How can I add a hover-text (i.e. a text box containing some explanation or details appearing when I hover with the mouse over a component) to TextFields, Tabs, Links, Labels, etc.

I googled and scanned the "Book of Vaadin" as well as "Building Modern Web Apps ..." books and neither contains any relevant info on hover-texts.

Have I missed something? Or are they known under some different term?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set tooltip hint for \`Select\` widget in Vaadin Flow 14](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59742361/set-tooltip-hint-for-select-widget-in-vaadin-flow-14)

Answer (score 4):

For example you can add a title:

```
yourComponent.getElement().setAttribute("title", "Your Explanation");
```

Read more about the title attribute in the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title

Answer (score 3):

If the native `title` attribute is not enough, you can look into add-ons. The Vaadin Directory has a [Tooltips4Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltips4vaadin/overview), or [Tooltip](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tooltip/overview). The second one is CVAL 3.0 licensed, but I believe it should be Apache 2.0. At least [the corresponding web component](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/vaadin-component-factoryvcf-tooltip) is Apache 2.0.